# Inline-кнопка «Добавить бота в чат»

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

Как, используя библиотеку telebot, я могу реализовать inline-кнопку, которая позволяет быстро добавить бота в чат (как левая кнопка на скриншоте)?

[image: Образец кнопки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам же дошёл до решения: достаточно создать URL-кнопку, ведущую на адрес формата `https://t.me/my_bot?startgroup=start`, где вместо `my_bot` вставить ID бота.
Вот пример кода такой кнопки:

```
telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Добавить бота в группу', url='https://t.me/examplebot?startgroup=start'))
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]